# Как сделать чтобы скрипт сам не срабатывал при загрузке страницы, а запускался только по кнопкам вкл и выкл

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <div onclick="stopsnow()" id="snow-start">Выкл. снег</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var snowsrc="http://all-blogspot.com/blog/img/snow.png";
  var no = 40; 
  var log = 0;
  var hidesnowtime = 0;
  var snowdistance = "windowheight";

  var ie4up = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
  var ns6up = (document.getElementById&&!document.all) ? 1 : 0;

    function iecompattest(){
    return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
    }

  var dx, xp, yp;    
  var am, stx, sty;  
  var i, doc_width = 800, doc_height = 600; 

  if (ns6up) {
    doc_width = self.innerWidth;
    doc_height = self.innerHeight;
  } else if (ie4up) {
    doc_width = iecompattest().clientWidth;
    doc_height = iecompattest().clientHeight;
  }

  dx = new Array();
  xp = new Array();
  yp = new Array();
  am = new Array();
  stx = new Array();
  sty = new Array();
  snowsrc=(snowsrc.indexOf("all-blogspot.com")!= 1)? "http://all-blogspot.com/blog/img/snow.png" : snowsrc
  for (i = 0; i < no; ++ i) {  
    dx[i] = 0;                        
    xp[i] = Math.random()*(doc_width-50); 
    yp[i] = Math.random()*doc_height;
    am[i] = Math.random()*20;      
    stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random()/10;
    sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();   
        if (ie4up||ns6up) {
      if (i == 0) {
        document.write("<div id=\"dot"+ i +"\" style=\"POSITION: fixed; Z-INDEX: "+ i +"; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='"+snowsrc+"' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
      } else {
        document.write("<div id=\"dot"+ i +"\" style=\"POSITION: fixed; Z-INDEX: "+ i +"; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='"+snowsrc+"' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
      }
    }
  }

  function snowIE_NS6() {  
    doc_width = ns6up?window.innerWidth-10 : iecompattest().clientWidth-10;
        doc_height=(window.innerHeight && snowdistance=="windowheight")? window.innerHeight : (ie4up && snowdistance=="windowheight")?  iecompattest().clientHeight : (ie4up && !window.opera && snowdistance=="pageheight")? iecompattest().scrollHeight : iecompattest().offsetHeight;
    for (i = 0; i < no; ++ i) { 
      yp[i] += sty[i];
      if (yp[i] > doc_height-50) {
        xp[i] = Math.random()*(doc_width-am[i]-30);
        yp[i] = 0;
        stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random()/10;
        sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
      }
      dx[i] += stx[i];
      document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.top=yp[i]+"px";
      document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.left=xp[i] + am[i]*Math.sin(dx[i])+"px";  
    }
    snowtimer=setTimeout("snowIE_NS6()", 10);
  }

    function hidesnow(){
        if (window.snowtimer) clearTimeout(snowtimer)
        for (i=0; i<no; i++) document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.visibility="hidden";
    }

if (ie4up||ns6up){
    snowIE_NS6();
        if (hidesnowtime>0)
        setTimeout("hidesnow()", hidesnowtime*1000);
        }
 function stopsnow(){
 if (log==0){
  for (i=0; i<no; i++) document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.visibility="hidden";
  no = 0;
  log = 1;
  document.getElementById('snow-start').innerHTML ='Вкл. снег';
  }
  else { log = 0; no = 20; for (i=0; i<no; i++) document.getElementById("dot"+i).style.visibility="visible";
 document.getElementById('snow-start').innerHTML ='Выкл. снег';

  }

 }
</script>
<a id="copy" href="http://all-blogspot.com/"></a>
<style>
#snow-start{
background: rgba(27, 25, 25, 0.4);
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
line-height: 25px;
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 9px;
}
#copy{
color: rgba(20, 16, 16, 0);
font-size: 7px;
position: fixed;
text-decoration: none;
top: 24px;
right: 2px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Это очень просто - заверните весь код в функцию (или в несколько функций) и вызывайте ее (или их) по нажатию на кнопки.

Comment: Можете показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var snowsrc = "http://all-blogspot.com/blog/img/snow.png";
var no = 40;
var log = 1;
var hidesnowtime = 0;
var snowdistance = "windowheight";

var ie4up = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
var ns6up = (document.getElementById && !document.all) ? 1 : 0;

function iecompattest() {
  return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") ? document.documentElement : document.body
}

var dx, xp, yp;
var am, stx, sty;
var i, doc_width = 800,
  doc_height = 600;

if (ns6up) {
  doc_width = self.innerWidth;
  doc_height = self.innerHeight;
} else if (ie4up) {
  doc_width = iecompattest().clientWidth;
  doc_height = iecompattest().clientHeight;
}

dx = new Array();
xp = new Array();
yp = new Array();
am = new Array();
stx = new Array();
sty = new Array();
snowsrc = (snowsrc.indexOf("all-blogspot.com") != 1) ? "http://all-blogspot.com/blog/img/snow.png" : snowsrc;
for (i = 0; i < no; ++i) {
  dx[i] = 0;
  xp[i] = Math.random() * (doc_width - 50);
  yp[i] = Math.random() * doc_height;
  am[i] = Math.random() * 20;
  stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10;
  sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
  if (ie4up || ns6up) {
    if (i == 0) {
      document.write("<div id=\"dot" + i + "\" style=\"visibility:hidden;POSITION: fixed; Z-INDEX: " + i + "; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='" + snowsrc + "' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
    } else {
      document.write("<div id=\"dot" + i + "\" style=\"visibility:hidden;POSITION: fixed; Z-INDEX: " + i + "; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 15px; LEFT: 15px;\"><img src='" + snowsrc + "' border=\"0\"><\/div>");
    }
  }
}
hidesnow();

function snowIE_NS6() {
  doc_width = ns6up ? window.innerWidth - 10 : iecompattest().clientWidth - 10;
  doc_height = (window.innerHeight && snowdistance == "windowheight") ? window.innerHeight : (ie4up && snowdistance == "windowheight") ? iecompattest().clientHeight : (ie4up && !window.opera && snowdistance == "pageheight") ? iecompattest().scrollHeight : iecompattest().offsetHeight;
  for (i = 0; i < no; ++i) {
    yp[i] += sty[i];
    if (yp[i] > doc_height - 50) {
      xp[i] = Math.random() * (doc_width - am[i] - 30);
      yp[i] = 0;
      stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10;
      sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
    }
    dx[i] += stx[i];
    document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.top = yp[i] + "px";
    document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.left = xp[i] + am[i] * Math.sin(dx[i]) + "px";
  }
  snowtimer = setTimeout("snowIE_NS6()", 10);
}

function hidesnow() {
  if (window.snowtimer) clearTimeout(snowtimer)
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++) document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.visibility = "hidden";
}

if (ie4up || ns6up) {
  snowIE_NS6();
  if (hidesnowtime > 0)
    setTimeout("hidesnow()", hidesnowtime * 1000);
}

function stopsnow() {
  if (log == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++) document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.visibility = "hidden";
    //no = 0;
    log = 1;
    document.getElementById('snow-start').innerHTML = 'Вкл. снег';
  } else {
    log = 0;
    //no = 20;
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++) document.getElementById("dot" + i).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('snow-start').innerHTML = 'Выкл. снег';

  }

}
```

```css
#snow-start {
  background: rgba(27, 25, 25, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 9px;
}

#copy {
  color: rgba(20, 16, 16, 0);
  font-size: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 24px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="stopsnow()" id="snow-start">Вкл. снег</div>
<a id="copy" href="http://all-blogspot.com/"></a>
```

Comment: Spasibo.Spasibo.

Comment: @КатяРяденская Пожалуйста. Успехов! Значок "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: IE4, NetScape Navigator... этому коду уже лет 20 :)

Comment: @Kosmos - а работает как новый )

Comment: @Igor - К - Качество :)